# Rename Mongo Shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Can I, and if I can, how can I rename a shard in Mongo?

Like if I wanted to change the instances of rs0 to rep0 below:

```
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 4,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 4,
    "currentVersion" : 5,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("111111111111")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "rs0",  "host" : "rs0/mongo0a:27017,mongo0b:27017" }
...
```

I have thought about removing and re-adding the shard, but I'm not sure how I'd do that without having to drain the shard and drop dbs.

Currently 0 of the collections have sharding enabled, I just have a few standalones added as shards.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no supported way to rename a shard at present, though as you mention you could remove and re-add.  Even then it is not as simple as you might think because although you can specify a name when adding a shard, it does not end there - there is the replica set itself to worry about.  The name specification when adding is just the value of the `_id`, see the following example (my replica set is rs0, like yours):

```
mongos> db.adminCommand({addShard : "rs0/host.example.com:27017,host.example.com:27018", name : "rep0"});

mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 4,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 4,
    "currentVersion" : 5,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("539838845bc6bf5ee52a56ea")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "rep0",  "host" : "rs0/host.example.com:27017,host.example.com:27018" }
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
```

Note that all that has changed is the `_id` for the shard, the `"host"` value remains the same, because `rs0` is the name of the replica set - if you try to use `rep0` there it will fail to add.  Hence, all that a remove and re-add will give you is a mismatch between the two names.

To change that `host` value, not only do you have to remove/re-add the shard, you also have to alter the replica set config before you re-add the shard.  In other words, the `replSet` parameter must be changed to be `rep0` also, and that means re-initializing the set - not an easy task either.

Overall, it is possible to get to where you want, but there will be a large amount of work and it will not be quick (drains, re-init of the set), especially if you have a lot of data.  For the sake of changing a couple of strings, I would generally recommend leaving them as-is.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not supported.  However, I have found a way to rename the shards.  Use at your own risk.

Basically, the shard name appears in the config servers in the following collections: config.databases, config.chunks, and config.shards.

Do a simple update to replace the fields that have the old shard name with the new shard name.  **You'll have to repeat this on all config servers.**  Shut down the shard servers and mongos clients first.  An example is below:

```
$ mongo <configserver>:<port>/config
configsvr> db.databases.update({primary:'old_shard_name'},{$set:{primary:'new_shard_name'}},{multi:true})
configsvr> db.chunks.update({shard:'old_shard_name'},{$set:{shard:'new_shard_name'}},{multi:true})
configsvr> var temp = db.shards.findOne({_id:'old_shard_name'})
configsvr> temp._id = 'new_shard_name'
configsvr> db.shards.remove({_id:'old_shard_name'})
configsvr> db.shards.insert(temp)
```

If you are changing the replica set name at the same time, you can modify the "hosts" field of the record in the config.shards collection at the same time.